# Free Shipping Coupon

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 
I've got a question.
We have 2 shipping metods, courier and post office
I would like to 'create coupon for free shipping' for post office shipping method.
Is it possible?
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Promotions > shopping cart price rules** , enter required details and select **Shipping method is : Post office** as below :

[image]

Below links will give you more information :

http://www.ifuelinteractive.com/how-to-create-a-free-shipping-coupon/

http://creatingawebstore.com/how-to-create-a-free-shipping-coupon-or-promotion-in-magento.html

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't working. In Conditions I Add :  Shipping method isn't [flatrate3] UPS but it's still free and post office to, Can you tell me why?

Comment: can you cross check configuration under `Actions` , did you selected `For shipment with matching items`.... ?

Comment: I did it and still the same. Post office and courier still free...

Comment: is it possible to try as i mentioned in answer , also make sure you selected : `If All of the conditions are true`.....

Comment: Done, and still the same

Comment: please check : `status = > Active , Website = > Main website , customer Groups selected or not , also please check from and to date`

Comment: Done, and it isn't working, free courier and postoffice. I would like make coupon for free post office.  here is link for screenshots : http://prnt.sc/enhudb http://prnt.sc/enhu8o http://prnt.sc/enhu5b

Comment: in scrrenshots, both flat rates are for post office ? also did you checked with subtotal also , means if subtotal is below 40, than `free shipping` will apply for all shipping methods....

Comment: also you may need to select `All` instead of `Any`

Comment: Please clear the cache and check.